# How to use prepareForSegue from inside a custom component that is inside a ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I got a custom component, (with its own Controller, and its own xib) which has a button. I made it using [this](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6) tutorial.

In main ViewController, I have four of these components, inside a ScrollView. I want the app to react to the clicking of that button preparing a segue.

I cannot do it from my custom component controller, because its an UIView, and cannot connect from the custom component to the main ViewController, because its not a direct sibling, there is a ScrollView. So, I cannot make an IBAction from the buttons in the View Controller of the Main.storyboard.

My goal is, from the custom component, create an IBAction in the Controller for the Main.storyboard, so I can start a segue and present one scene or another, depending of which button pressed the user.

How could I achieve this? Thank you.

My custom component controller:

```
    import UIKit

    @IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView {

    // Our custom view from the XIB file
    var view: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var icono: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func onClick(sender: UIButton) {
        println("button \(label.text!)")
        switch label.text!{
            case "Text 1":
                println("First component")

            case "Text 2":
                println("Second component")
            case "Text 3":
                println("Third component")
            case "Text 4":
                println("Fourth component")
            default:
                println("Error")
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage? {
        get {
            return icono.image
        }
        set(image) {
            icono.image = image
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var text: String? {
        get {
            return label.text
        }
        set (text){
            label.text=text
        }
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        view.frame = bounds

        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
        //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0)
        self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
        // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
        addSubview(view)

    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }
    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // 1. setup any properties here

        // 2. call super.init(frame:)
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // 1. setup any properties here

        // 2. call super.init(coder:)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }

}
```

My Main.storyboard's ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var customViewVirtual: CustomView!
@IBOutlet weak var customViewContactar: CustomView!
@IBOutlet weak var customViewPresenciales: CustomView!
@IBOutlet weak var customViewCalendario: CustomView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "fondo")!)
    customViewVirtual.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    customViewContactar.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    customViewPresenciales.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    customViewCalendario.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: How your custom component controller is a UIView? Where is the UIViewController which is holding your UIView?

Comment: I made a xib, and made a ViewController to control it. Then, in Main.storyboard, I added four views, making the class of that views the controller of my custom component, which is a instance of UIView. Im adding code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your ViewContoller (containing custom view) ctrl+drag to the ViewController you want to instantiate on UIView (sitting inside Scroll view) tap .

Now select the segue type and name it as you wish.
When UIView receives the tap call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];
```

[image: 1]

[image]

Edit: The delegate approach

CustomView.h

```
@protocol ButtonClickDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)didClickButton;
@end

@interface CustomView : UIView
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<ButtonClickDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

CustomView.m

```
@implementation CustomView

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    //check if delegate implemented the method
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didClickButton)])
    {
        //informing the delegate about action
        [self.delegate didClickButton];
    }
}

@end
```

ContainingViewController.h - confirms to ButtonClickDelegate

```
@interface ContainingViewController : UIViewController<ButtonClickDelegate>

@end
```

ContainingViewController.m

```
@interface ContainingViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) CustomView * customView;
@end

@implementation ContainingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //instantiate customView
    //set the delegate as self
    self.customView.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - ButtonClickDelegate method
-(void)didClickButton
{
    //custom view button was clicked
    //performing the segue
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];
}


@end
```

Comment: The problem is...I have four custom components (every one with his own button) in my Main.storyboard. So, depending of the button the user press, I need to prepare a segue to a different scene. And I cannot connect from custom component to Main.storyboard's ViewController to make an IBAction. And cannot call performSegueWithIdentifier from UIView, since is a UIViewController method.

Comment: Connect segues from custom views containing UIViewController to all possible view controllers you want to instantiate and name those segues uniquely. Depending upon button tag or something perform the desired segues.

Comment: Who contains your four custom components?

Comment: The Main.storyboard's ViewController. Added code for it in my question.

Comment: I am able to create my segues, and they got their Identifier. the problem is I cannot perform segues from the UIView, where I have the IBAction from the custom component button.

Comment: Use the delegate approach to pass the button click event from custom views to your containing view controller and perform the segue from there.

Comment: Searching how to do it. if it works, Ill upvote. Thank you anyway for your time and help.

Comment: Thanks but I am using Swift...will try to translate.